# "new Date().toLocaleString()" returning same time every time

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm running a Discord bot on Discord.js

I have a command that prints the current date and time by using `new Date().toLocaleString();` but I noticed that it prints the exact same date and time every time it's used. Am I using this wrong? I initially had it using `message.createdAt` but didn't like the format it displayed the date and time in.

EDIT:

It's literally just

```
var currentdate = new Date().toLocaleString();

if(command === "date") {
    message.channel.send(currentdate);
  }
```

But it's only ever accurate on the first use and every use after that prints the first given date and time.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAQDf.png)

EDIT 2:

Okay so it worked by just using `new Date().toLocaleString();` and not bothering with the variable. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: Just tried in console and its working fine. Can you please share a sample code that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guess (you provided too few lines btw) : you assign to "currentDate" the value of the exact moment in which it is called. But you don't repeat the check somewhere, so "currentDate" is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Its working properly.could you please provide code where your trying

**[image: strong text]**